# How can I log calls that are made to Firebase database via rest API?

Tags: rest, debugging, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to see and log the incoming calls to a firebase database? e.g.

```
GET 'https://XYZ.firebaseio.com/user/<RFID ID>/balance.json?auth=verysecrettoken'
```

Produce a log like:

> Time, Date: incoming call "GET 'https://XYZ.firebaseio.com/user//balance.json?auth=verysecrettoken'" - reponse was "1"

Comment: Maybe you could use Functions and listen to HTTP requests. Check this function sample https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Database servers don't provide an accessible log of the incoming requests.

If you want something like this you could consider setting up a proxy server. Or log the events from the client into something like the Firebase Realtime Database (yes, ironic, I know) or Firebase Analytics.

Comment: What about if the request is log using Functions, a function can listen to the desire HTTP request and log the important accessible info, can this be a valid alternative?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but it could well be that there is a way to accomplish the use case. I recommend you write it into an answer, so OP can determine if it's helpful for them.

Comment: Found something useful in the Functions samples, added as a comment, hope its helpfull